# Use cropVariants with FilesProcessor

Tags: typo3

I'm using the layout-field of tt_content to render textmedia in different ways. I get the images by using FilesProcessor.

```
tt_content.textmedia = CASE
tt_content.textmedia {
    key.field = layout
    default < temp.textmedia

    # newElement
    newElement = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    newElement {
        file = EXT:.../newElement.html
        dataProcessing.10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
        dataProcessing.10 {
            references {
                table = tt_content
                fieldName = assets
            }
            as = images
        }
    }
}
```

How can I access the cropVariants?

Answer (score 0):

Arghh…
Simple solution ...

```
temp.textmedia < tt_content.textmedia

tt_content.textmedia = CASE
tt_content.textmedia {
    key.field = layout
    default < temp.textmedia

    # newElement
    newElement < temp.textmedia
    newElement {
        templateName = MasonryGallery
    }
}
```